# arbitrary vs at the whim of somebody

Tags: sentence

I'd like to ask if these following sentences have the same meaning ?

> Hong Kong had been ruled at the whim of its colonial overlords.
>
> Hong Kong had been ruled by arbitrary colonial overlords.

And what should we infer from the sentences, ruler changes often and randomly or the way of their rule changes often and randomly?

Comment: Your final question is difficult to understand.  Can you rephrase it?

Comment: How should I do

Comment: You appear to be asking - 'And what should we infer from the sentences, *ruler changes often and randomly* or *the way of their rule changes often and randomly?*'  Even if this is correct it is almost impenetrable.  A little more context might help.  Is this a quote or are the phrases your own?

Comment: well I wanted to compare those and I looked up a sentence like the first sentence and I found it on the Internet and changed it by adding "arbitrary" and omitting "at the whim of" part.

Comment: Arbitrary and whimsical are not the same - see post below.

Comment: The second statement is ambiguous.  Taken one way it means almost exactly what the first means -- the rules changed randomly & without reason -- but taken the other way it means the rulers changed randomly & without reason.  The first way, the behavior of the overlords is arbitrary, while under the second interpretation their selection is arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the same.

To rule *whimsically* is to rule unpredictably, according only to personal (and quite possibly unfathomable) rules and impulses.

'*Arbitrary*...overlords' are randomly chosen without thought to their suitability for the job (they may turn out to be good).

Comment: It's actually ambiguous in OP's second sentence as the whether the overlords are abitrary in their rule, or whether the ruling overlords were arbitrarily selected for rule.

Comment: @Jim really?  *Hong Kong had been ruled by arbitrary colonial overlords* is not the same as *Hong Kong had been ruled arbitrarily by colonial overlords*.

Comment: @Jim do you think the second sentence is grammatically correct even though it is ambiguous or should I say " arbitrary of overlords"

Comment: Yes, second sentence is grammatical.  I'm just saying it can be interpeted as "had been ruled by overlords that were arbitrary [in their decisions]" or "had been ruled by arbitrarily selected overlords"

Comment: @Jim   how about " Locke was worried about the absolute arbitrary power of kings"

Comment: The set up of the second sentence (Hong Kong as a **colony** ruled by ..) encourages the '...*arbitrarily selected*...' interpretation.

Comment: I see thanks, can we rephrase the sentence "Locke was worried about the absolute arbitrary power of kings" by using " at the whim of kings"

Comment: There is no ambiguity in your new sentence *'Locke was worried ...*' for me.  Arbitrary in this case clearly describes the way they exercised their  power.